# React Class Component Separate UI & Business Logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, architecture

I am trying to separate UI and Logic in React class component with little bit of js. I know this could be done easily with custom hooks. But I need to do with class components.

I could make some progress, but it doesnot seem efficient, need your input.

`App.view.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import ListWrapper from "../components/ListWrapper";
import SearchField from "../components/SearchField";
import UserCard from "../components/UserCard";
import AppController from "./App.controller";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { users: [], searchValue: "" };
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppController(this.state, this.setState).fetchUsers();
  }

  render() {
    const filteredUsers = AppController(
      this.state,
      this.setState
    ).handleFilter();

    return (
      <div className="wrapper pb-12 bg-gray-100 mx-auto max-w-7xl">
        <Header heading=" Pets Rolodex" />
        <SearchField
          labelText="Search Pets"
          fieldId="pets-search-field"
          placeholderText="Enter name"
          searchValue={this.state.searchValue}
          handleChange={AppController(this.state, this.setState).handleChange}
          className="w-72"
        />
        <ListWrapper
          listData={filteredUsers}
          ListItem={UserCard}
          ListItemProp="user"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`App.controller.js`

```js
const AppController = (state, setState) => ({
  // Fetch Users info
  fetchUsers: () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setState({ users: data }))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  },

  // Input Field Handler
  handleChange: event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setState({ searchValue: value });
  },

  // Filter Handler
  handleFilter: () => {
    const { searchValue, users } = state;
    if (searchValue === "") {
      return users;
    } else {
      return users.filter(usr =>
        usr.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }
});

export default AppController;
```

This works fine. [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-separation-of-concerns-wlnr49)

But the issue is, this instantiates multiple objects from function calls `AppController(this.state, this.setState)` and this happens on every `render(){...}` It is like I am creating and destroying function stored in memory.

#### What I tried

I moved the function call to constructor like below:

```js
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { users: [], searchValue: "" };
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
    this.controller = AppController(this.state, this.setState)
  }
```

and used `this.controller` everywhere in view.

But this seems to persist initial state (empty) into function's execution context and all logic functions inside it never see a light of new state.

Thanks in advance for your input :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "instantiates", there's only one controller. Do you mean the function call returning the object? That aside, the controller still seems tied to the UI; if the primary purpose is fetching data why not have it just fetch the data and leave state mgmt up to the React side?

Comment: by "instantiates" I mean function calls which returns an object, as you said :) It is not just fetching data from API. I want to push out all tiny handlers also. Only UI components needs to be there in view, that would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor the `AppController` to class and pass the component instance to its constructor.

E.g.

`App.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Controller from "./controller";

class App extends React.Component<any, { users: any[]; searchValue: string }> {
  controller: InstanceType<typeof Controller>;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { users: [], searchValue: "" };
    this.controller = new Controller(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.controller.fetchUsers();
  }

  render() {
    const filteredUsers = this.controller.handleFilter();
    return (
      <ul>
        {filteredUsers.map((user) => (
          <li key={user.key}>{user.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

`controller.ts`:

```
class Controller {
  compInstance;
  constructor(compInstance) {
    this.compInstance = compInstance;
  }
  // Fetch Users info
  fetchUsers() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => this.compInstance.setState({ users: data }))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }

  // Input Field Handler
  handleChange(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.compInstance.setState({ searchValue: value });
  }

  // Filter Handler
  handleFilter() {
    const { searchValue, users } = this.compInstance.state;
    if (searchValue === "") {
      return users;
    } else {
      return users.filter((usr) =>
        usr.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Controller;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-view-controller-sohsvv?file=/index.tsx)

Comment: Thanks, I liked the way you passed `compInstance` while initializing object in component. This makes it neat :)